# How can I convert a list to named variables in Python?

Tags: python, list

Is there a quick way in python to convert a list of values to named variables?

For example:

```
row = ['files', 'file.pdf', 'D1234', 43]      

folder = row[0]
name = row[1]
doc_id = row[2]
page_num = row[3]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
folder, name, doc_id, page_num = row
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was something simple..I was looking for 'list expansion' or something...

Comment: @roemhildtg If you liked this answer, consider checking it

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below patterns to do it more professionally

```
v = ['files', 'file.pdf', 'D1234', 43]    
keys = ['folder', 'name', 'doc_id', 'page_num']
junk = map(lambda k, v: dict.update({k: v}), keys, values)
```

Comment: What makes you call this "more professional" than the other answer?